A variant of the partition problem or subset sum problem
Given a target list $T = (t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_N)$ and a multiset $S = \{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_M\}$, both with non-negative integer elements, $t_k\in \mathbb{N}_>$ and $s_k\in \mathbb{N}_>$, determine whether there exists a partitioning of $S$ into $N$ disjoint subsets, $\{S_q\}_{q=1}^{N}$ with $S_q\subset S$, such that
$$
\sum_{s \in S_q} s = t_q.
$$
for all $q = 1, \ldots, N$ and such that $\bigcup_q S_q = S$ and $S_q\cap S_{q'} = \emptyset$ if $q\ne q'$.
This seems to be a variant of the multiway number partition problem or some form of a (multiple) subset sum problem, except that the target sum is now a list $T = (t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_N)$ instead of a single number.
Questions:

Is this problem in fact identical to one of these problems (or a related known problem) under a suitable mapping.

Are there any algorithms or frameworks that would be suitable to solve this computationally (typical scenarios would have $N, M < 5$ and $T_k < 6$; often smaller)?

Can this be phrased as a binary linear feasibility problem or similar?



As context, the "motivating" problem is this:
Given a target list $T = (T_1, \ldots, T_N)$, a set of multisets ${S^{(j)}}{j=1}^{J}$ with $S^{(j)} = {s_1^{(j)}, \ldots, s{N^{(j)}}^{(j)}}$, and a multiset $R = {r_1, \ldots, r_L}$, determine if there exist disjoint subset selections ${S_q^{(j)}}$ and ${R_q}$ in $S^{(j)}$ and $R$, s.t.:
$$ \sum_{s \in S_q^{(j)}} s = t_q + \sum_{r\in R_q} r $$
for all $j, q$ and with $\bigcup_q S_q^{(j)} = S^{(j)}$ and $\bigcup_q R_q = R$ (and $S_q^{(j)} \cap S_{q'}^{(j)} = R_q\cap R_{q'} = \emptyset$ if $q\ne q'$).

Ignoring the $R$-related term, this breaks into a series of problems of the simpler kind in the question above. With the $R$-term, it is not clear to me whether this is so.
Any insights on this would be appreciated.

Both the problem in your question and the motivating problem are easily modeled binary integer programs (feasibility problems). Both can also be set up as constraint programming problems.

Would be happy to accept an answer that describes the modelling of this as a binary integer program.

An answer to the scaling of this problem in $N$ and $M$ would still be of interest to me, however. Mostly, is this in NP or P?

Answering my own question partially, in the vein suggested by @prubin:
The original problem can be reformulated as a binary integer feasibility problem by introducing binary variables $x_{kq}$ with $k = 1, \ldots, M$ and $q = 1, \ldots, N$. Then, the original problem is solvable if there exists binary $x_{kq}$ such that:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k = 1}^M x_{kq} s_k = t_q 
 \quad \forall q = 1, \ldots, N
\qquad
&\text{(sum constraint: }\sum_{s\in S_q}s = t_q\text{)}
\\
&\sum_{q = 1}^N \sum_{k=1}^M x_{kq} = M
\qquad
&\text{(cover entire set $S$: }\bigcup_q S_q = S\text{)}
\\
&\sum_{q=1}^M  x_{kq} = 1
\quad \forall k = 1, \ldots, M
\qquad
&\text{(disjoint subsets: } S_q\cap S_{q'} = \emptyset \text{ if } q\ne q'\text{)}
\end{align}
And the feasible subsets $S_q$ are then given by:
$$
S_q = \bigcup_{k} \begin{cases}
s_k & \text{if } x_{kq} =  1\\
\emptyset & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
This can be solved with e.g., the Cbc solver. A minimal implementation in Julia, using JuMP is:
using JuMP, Cbc

S = [1, 3, 5, 2]
T = [4, 7]

M, N = length(S), length(T), 

m = Model(Cbc.Optimizer)
@variable(m, x[1:M, 1:N], Bin)
for q in 1:N
    @constraint(m, sum(x[k, q]*S[k] for k in 1:M) == T[q])
end
@constraint(m, sum(x[k, q] for k in 1:M for q in 1:N) == M)
for k in 1:M
    @constraint(m, sum(x[k,q] for q in 1:N) == 1)
end

optimize!(m)
if is_solved_and_feasible(m)
   value.(x) # optimized values x_{kq} as a matrix
end


Your second constraint is redundant, being an aggregation of the third set of constraints.
